# How to empty Cloudant databases from the GUI?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, acralyzer

I have three databases with a bunch of documents that I didn't need. I tried to purge them using the Acralyzer, but apparently they're still sitting there, flipping me the exclamation marks. How do I empty these databases completely using the Cloudant GUI without deleting the databases themselves?

[image: how do delete documents completely from the cloudant GUI]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. Cloudant (and CouchDB) retain a "tombstone" document for each deleted document. This means that if a databases is replicated elsewhere, then you delete a document or two and replicate the remote changes back in, we don't accidentally resurrect the deleted documents.

The warning asterisks in the dashboard are simply bringing to your attention that you have a fairly large proportion of deleted documents against your undeleted documents.

If you are desperate to have a clean database, then you would have to create a new database and replicate over the documents but the exclude deletions (using [Filtered replication](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/guides/replication_guide.html#filtered-replication), but as it stands, you don't have anything to worry about.